# Apache Tomcat performance tuning with NGINX and?

Tags: mysql, performance, apache, tomcat

at the moment I just have Apache Tomcat and a mysql db on my server (4x3,5ghz, 16gb) for a Website with heavey dynamic content and it works well.
But in 2 weeks a big TV commercial starts so that heavey load is expected.

How can I tune the Tomcat server?

I raised the tomcat threads to 500 and thats it.
What about Ngnix and other things I dont know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voting to close this as it's WAY too broad. But a quick couple of hints

- use a CDN (but mke sure is geoDNS aware)
- install and configure ngx_pagespeed
- make sure your logging all queries in MySQL slow query log and start looking for the problems now